# Static methods with Spring MVC and tomcat

Tags: spring, tomcat, static

What will happen if I use static methods (say from a utility class that I created) with Spring MVC.
Moreover, my static methods are not synchronized.
What may happen if multiple requests call the same method at same time.

Comment: Why don't you try and see?

Comment: Do those static methods reference static variables or just local variables within the method?

Comment: Most of them use variables local to the method but they have arguments too. But what if two requests call the same method at the same time with different argument values.

Answer (score 1):

Its OK to use static methods if you know what you're doing. If in your static method you're using only local variables ( not fields in a class ) you should then be thread-safe too. Otherwise - it is up to you do handle the synchronization and locking to keep data consistent.

Spring has a limitation that you cannot use `static` on setters of spring beans.